# I want to archive the emails I have in the inbox before reading it. What is the solution for this?

Tags: email, archiving, email-client, workspace, autoarchive

I have an email that I opened with Outlook, I opened it with thunderbird and even opened it with BlueMail.
For me, using each one of them is not different.
It is important to me that I can archive the Inbox.
Because when I get the email, I delete it because of space limits.

Comment: what "archive" exactly means for you? What you've tried? How it didn't succeed? ...

Comment: I have a mailbox that is limited to 500 MB.
The number of emails I receive per day is high and  It will be filled up soon.
Several users use this email.
Due to tracking, I have to have a copy of the emails.
I want to have an archive of emails on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case someone else is wondering...

One option would be to change your settings to use the POP3 protocol instead of IMAP. If you are running Outlook or Thunderbird on your local computer, changing the account settings to POP3 will cause the emails to download to your hard drive. Outlook and Thunderbird both have an option to specify how many days the emails will be left on the server. If multiple people access the emails, everyone else can use IMAP, so that only your computer's program will control when emails are automatically deleted after download to your computer.

Tip: Use a backup program to back up emails you have downloaded, in case your email program crashes and needs to be reinstalled.

If multiple people use POP3, they will each be downloading the same emails until one of the email programs deletes them from the server. The device that specifies the shortest number of days will be the one that deletes them first. (My version of Outlook leaves them on the server for 14 days by default; I usually change that to 30 days.) If you want to be sure that nobody else's program deletes them automatically, have them use IMAP.

There are also programs that can copy and delete automatically from the server. MailStore Home is one of them (though I've only used it for local archiving from emails already on my computer).

Comment: My main problem is backup. What service do you introduce?